# Angular 4 pipe data in array from API observable

Tags: angular, api, typescript, pipe

Im trying to create a filter for my stories. I subscribe to the API call, and i get the data as an array of objects. I get this error, when im typing in the filterings.
I've only included the relevant parts, but i can provide more if needed.
Im not that great to Pipes in Angular 4, so any tips would be helpful! Thank you.

[image]

This is the responsedata:

[image: Response]

Pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DiscoverComponent } from './discover/discover.component'


@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  //transform is called every time that the input changes in the filter pipe
  transform(stories: any, term: any): any {
    //check if search term is undefined and return all stories
    if(term === undefined) return stories;
    // return updated storiesarray with filter
    return stories.filter((story) => {
      return story.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) //either true or false
    })
  }

}
```

Component:

```
private getStories(page, hits, feed) {
    feed = this.feed;
    if (this.noSpam || this.page > 0) { //no doubletap feed
      this.noSpam = false;
      this.storiesService.getStories(this.page, this.hits, this.feed)
        .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          console.log(data);
          if (!data || data.hits == 0 || data.hits < 6) {
            this.finished = true;
            console.log("No more hits :(")
          } else {
            this.finished = false;
            // this.data = data;
            for (let story of data.hits) {
              this.hitsArray.push(story);
              // console.log(data)
            }
          }
        })
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("Wait 2 seconds before trying to get feed!")
        this.noSpam = true;
      }, this.delay);

      console.log("side: " + this.page)
    }
  }
```

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="term" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" type="text" id="bloody-bird-forms" class="form-control">
```

And

```
<div class="col-xs col-sm col-md-4 col-lg-4 story" *ngFor="let story of hitsArray | filter:term">
```

Comment: Read https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Comment: So basically this means that angular doesnt provide filtering arrays?

Comment: It's plain English. It means it doesn't provide a filter and an orderBy pipe, and that it's a deliberate choice because it's a bad idea. So you shouldn't try creating one yourself, but instead filter from the component when the term changes.

Comment: Okay. So if i wanted to filter data in an array from the component, when the term changes, how do you suggest i do that?

Comment: `<input [(ngModel)]="term" (ngModelChange)="filterTheArray()" .../>`.

Comment: And the `filterTheArray()` function should contain the logic from the pipe filter that i originally created i presume?

Comment: Yes, of course. It needs to create a filtered copy of the original array and store that copy in the component. And the ngFor needs to iterate on that filtered array (which initially, is the same as the original array).

Comment: Ok, i will try your suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ngFor with asychnronous data you have to use pipe 'async'. And after that you can use second, third pipe. Important is what order pipes have. First should be async, because order of executing is from left to right. If you want to use pipe in your controller you have to import that pipe and use like this.

```
const newString = pipename.transform(oldString);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems stories is either undefined or null, change your pipe as follows,

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  //transform is called every time that the input changes in the filter pipe
  transform(stories: any, term: any): any {
    //check if search term is undefined and return all stories
    if(!stories) return [];
    if(stories && term === undefined) return stories;
    // return updated storiesarray with filter
    if(stories && storiess.length > 0){
    return stories.filter((story) => {
      return story.name.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) //either true or false
    })}
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that made this error: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined". Also theres one to many "s" in `storiess.length>0` right?

Comment: yes but the idea is you need to check values are there

Comment: Sure, but i don't see how this affects the array, as the length is more than 6 objects in the array atm?